# Usar Smarty variables en JavaScript con innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

Tengo variable de Smarty (PrestaShop) `{$cart_qties}`. Como puedo usarlo en un script?
Por ejemplo

```
<script>
if ("{$cart_qties}" > 5) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "MAS de 5";   
}
</script>

<p id="demo">MENOS de 5</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar las llaves `{literal}{/literal}` para tener en cuenta el código `Javascript` y dejar sin englobar dentro de estas llaves la variable, tal y como indican en el **[foro de Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=150)**:

```
{literal} 
if ({/literal}{$cart_qties}{literal} > 5) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "MAS de 5";   
}
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, tienes que tener en cuenta que las llaves que se usan para indicar que son variables smarty, también se usan en el lenguaje de javascript, si lo que quieres es usar una variables en javascript lo mas fácil sería algo así:

```
<script> 
var numero = {$cart_qties};
{literal} 
if (numero > 5) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "MAS de 5"; 
}
{/literal}
</script>
```

Como ves, lo que hago es obtener los valores antes de hacer uso a las llaves de javascript, las cuales, estan englobadas dentro de la etiqueta literal.

Un saludo, espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score -1):

por ejemplo este codigo funcciona bien

```
{if {$cart_qties} < 5 }
<span> menos de 5 </span>
{else}
<span> mas de 5 </span>
{/if}
```

Pero sin innerHTML tengo que refrescar la página para actualizar lo que tiene que aparecer. Por eso quiero meterlo en script